# Why BitmapDecoder doesen't work?

Tags: java, android, url, bitmap

i'm trying to download some images in internet and paste them into the screen with gridview.. but when i use the BitmapDecoder option the images dowsen't appear.. if i don't use that (only download) the images appear in the screen :/

```
 URL url = new URL(src);
 Rect padding = new Rect(8,8,8,8);
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 connection.setDoInput(true);
 connection.connect();
 InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
 final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
 BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, padding , options);
 options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 300, 300);
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, padding, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't decode from the same input stream twice. The best options are to save the file to disk immediately and decode it from there, or to read the input stream into a byte array and then decode the byte array.

Comment: ok, i change the code and i create a new input stream.. the problem now is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492428/downloading-bitmap-error

the app run in the VM but in my tablet no :(